# Syntax for passing Multidimensional array

Tags: apex, list, string

I have a method in my controller util file that parses through some strings to find matches
I need to pass in a multidimensional array.  When I call this method in various controllers how in Apex do instantiate a

```
List<List<String>>
```

Util class has this:

```
public static Boolean hasPreference(List<List<String>> preferenceMatches){
    [code that parses is in here, not relevant to my question]
}
```

Comment: Shame on the drive-by-downvoters. Downvoting without explanation doesn't help people figure out what to do differently next time. I, myself, think this is a fine question (though you may want to take a look at [formatting help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make your future questions easier to read).

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say the downvotes are because your question, as asked, is extremely basic. I have my doubts that you don't know how to pass parameters, so I think that your real question is about something else. If you're asking about how to add values to a `List<List<String>>`, please [edit] your question to reflect that. If that isn't it, some additional explanation of what exactly you're stuck on would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses.  I only just started posting questions regarding coding.  I'm fresh out of college and new to salesforce so sorry if my question was too vague or the format sub-par.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could prepare a script for your understanding.

**prepare the array**

```
List<List<String>> preferenceMatchesList = new List<List<String>();
for(Integer n=0;n<3;n++)
{
    List<String> lstStr = new List<String>();
    for(Integer i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        lstStr.add('Value' + n + i);        
    }
    preferenceMatchesList.add(lstStr);
}

System.debug(preferenceMatchesList);
```

> DEBUG|preferenceMatches=((Value00, Value01, Value02, Value03, Value04), (Value10, Value11, Value12, Value13, Value14), (Value20, Value21, Value22, Value23, Value24))

**pass the array to the method**

```
if (hasPreference(preferenceMatchesList))
{
    //do something

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You pass the parameter just like you'd pass any other parameter.

That is, if you have a variable such as `List<List<String>> myMultidimensionalStringList`, your method call would be

```
Util.hasPreference(myMultidimensionalStringList);
```

I don't think that's what you're actually asking about though. If I had to take a guess, I'd guess that your actual question is how to get data into such a variable in the first place.

There are a few different ways you could approach this, which I'll illustrate below.

```
// The thing to realize in all of these examples is that the outermost level
//   is a List of Lists.
// This is a bit different from the multidimensional arrays in C++, for example.
// Instead of simply adding values directly to the List<List<String>> at your target
//   indices, you'll need to store your values in lists, and then add those lists
//   to your List<List>.

// First, using curly braces to initialize a list directly.
// I wouldn't recommend doing this directly in a method call
myMultidimensionalStringList = new List<List<String>>{
    new List<String>{'a', 'b', 'c'},
    new List<String>{'1', '2', '3'},
    new List<String>{'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
};

// Second, adding empty lists to the outermost list, and then adding values
myMultidimensionalStringList = new List<List<String>>();

// You can use the curly brace initialization here too
myMultidimensionalStringList.add(new List<String>{'a', 'b', 'c'});
// ...or add a completely empty list and populate values as you go
myMultidimensionalStringList.add(new List<String>());
myMultidimensionalStringList[1].add('1');
myMultidimensionalStringList[1].add('2');
myMultidimensionalStringList[1].add('3');

// Third, using loops, which cuts down on the amount of code you have to write
List<String> tempList;
for(MyObject__c myObj :[<some query here>]){
    tempList = new List<String>();
    tempList.add(myObj.someField__c);
    tempList.add(myObj.someOtherField__c);

    myMultidimensionalStringList.add(tempList);
}
```